# Installing cx_Oracle on AWS Glue

Tags: sqlalchemy, psycopg2, aws-glue

While adding cx_Oracle either as additional python module, or as wheel it always shows below error;

DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help

I tried editing the rpath of the libclntsh.so, adding ojdbc8.jar driver, but to no avail.

Please dont mark as duplicate. I have looked at other answers, but they are not satisfactory.

Comment: For future readers, the latest Oracle DB driver for Python doesn't necessarily need Instant Client, which makes deployment easier.  The driver got renamed from cx_Oracle to python-oracledb, see https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already installed the instant client libraries. Then you are probably missing this step:

> sudo sh -c "echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_1 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"
>
> sudo ldconfig

This assumes that you installed the .so libraries on the /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_1 directory